# Excel: better way to handle living document with multiple simultaneous authors

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, synchronization, onedrive

The department I work in has an Excel document on a SharePoint drive that multiple simultaneous people edit throughout the day. The dataset/worksheet is around 80k rows with 37 columns, and the file size itself with VBA macros is around 20Meg.

The issue is with the amount of people in at a time (up to 6), there often is sync issues where excel can't merge changes and then end up with multiple instances of files that need to get re-correlated which wastes a far amount of time and is hard to determine which edits came when.

I've tried searching google for sync issues but nothing really points to how to optimize the file/system to decrease this from happening.

I've argued that this isn't the best way to go about this and to break up the data and assign it to individuals (parse it out into separate files that get combined at end of day), but management wants none of that as, well, change.

Any thoughts - experience - direct link pointers on how how to properly manage multiple simultaneous users in a SharePoint Excel workbook to ease sync issues?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As soon as I read the title, I thought of separate files (smaller - easier to update) which are then linked to the master file, macro written to call each separate file to get updates before running analysis. But you exclude that so I have no other suggestion.

Comment: Similar as @SolarMike, but I thought database.  Have also been in your position.  Unfortunately the world is run by luddite managers.

Comment: The simple answer is "don't."  If you're forced into that box, you really want to spend some time either working on the above, or treat the spreadsheet like a repository where you have a separate file with a userform to enter data, then that data is sent to the repository (excel is not a database).  You'll still run into issues with people updating simultaneously (but it should be less often) as there is not an inherent queue system for the uploads to the repository.  Your best option is to not use the software this way, which isn't what anyone (management) wants to hear.

Comment: The last time I did this, and it was noticeable to decrease the amount of lost data, I used a spreadsheet for the userform (excel hidden so only the userform was visible), vbs to combine the info into the respository, and a repository workbook.  I made it take 10 seconds for each upload as part of the vbs, where the data is sent TWICE to the repository (think `do until match`), once to append and the second to verify it was appended... this was all stored on a network drive.  Thank you management for forcing us into that wheelhouse.